# Reconstructing a finite group by the IMAGE of itself in its representations, i.e its relevant quotients

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

There are many interesting questions about reconstructing a group from its representations.

To fix notation. let $G$ be a finite group, $V_i, r_i:G\to End(V_i)$ its irreducible representations.

We know that-

1. Given the maps (charactres) $\chi_i :G \to \mathbb{C}$, one cannot reconstruct $G$.
2. Given the ring $\mathbb{C}[G]$, one cannot reconstruct $G$.
3. Given the maps (of sets) $r_i$, one CAN reconstruct $G$.

My question is, given the images $Im(r_i)$, can we reconstruct $G$? We need to be careful if we want different results for $G= Z/pZ$ and $G \oplus G$. We include the multiplicity of the images for this (in particular you DO know the size of $G$).

This is weaker than $3$, and different from $1,2$.

The example of $D8$, $Q_8$ which show $1$ do not solve my question- their two dimensional representations are faithful.

Comment: @Joppy , I dont get your argument, but I think you're right even for abelian it fails by taking Zp vs Zp+Zp

Comment: Actually, I think you need to be more precise. If $G$ is irreducible representations labelled $r_1, \ldots, r_n$, are you giving me each of the images of $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ separately? Would I know immediately that $G$ had $n$ irreducible representations?

Comment: @Joppy Yup that's what I'm thinking as well, let's do that, I'll add it to the post

Comment: My guess is that the answer is no, this does not determine $G$, because there are collections of groups (particularly $p$-groups) that are really very similar and hard to distinguish, but it might be hard to find a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two groups $G = \mathtt{SmallGroup}(32,30)$ and $H = \mathtt{SmallGroup}(32,31)$ appear to be a counterexample.

They both have $8$ irreducible linear characters and $6$ of dimension $2$.

The $7$ nontrivial linear characters all have image of order $2$, two of the others have image of order $8$, and the other $4$ have image of order $16$.

In both groups, the images of order $8$ are all dihedral, and all of those of order $16$ are isomorphic to $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(16,13)$, which is a central product of a dihedral group of order $8$ and a cyclic group of order $4$.

I did these calculations in Magma, and they could also easily be done in GAP. The method was to compute the character tables of $G$ and $H$ and then identify (as abstract groups) their quotients by their kernels.

Comment: Thanks! Crazy how nature make dat